# Editing Exif orientation tag for my images

Tags: linux, image, jpeg, exif, exiftool

I want to change the Exif orientation tag in my JPEG images but without actual rotating of them, I want to do that to use them as a test case for an application I made. How I can do that in Linux, can't it done with Exiftools? If so, how?

Comment: Install `jhead`. Then do `$ man jhead`.

Comment: Are you looking for a command line tool? C source code? A Java library?

Comment: command line tool, or a Linux program

Answer (score 1):

Something like `exiftran -9 -ni -o modified.jpg original.jpg` works well for me. The `-9` causes the EXIF orientation to be rotated 90 degrees clockwise, but the `-ni` causes the image to be left intact, with the end result being the image rotates 270 degrees clockwise. Instead of `-9`, use `-1` to rotate 180 degrees, or `-2` to rotate 270 degrees.